# Sending packets to Minecraft PE

Tags: ios, objective-c, minecraft, handshake

I'm working at application that works with Minecraft PE servers. I am currently at the position of creating the handshake with the server. Looking at this page http://wiki.vg/Protocol I understand that the status ping works as follows:

```
C->S : Handshake State=1  
C->S : Request  
S->C : Response  
C->S : Ping  
S->C : Pong
```

C is client and S is server. But I don't understand what bytes/data/hex I need to send. I use https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket to connect and here is the code:

```
error = nil;
BOOL successs = [self.clientSocket connectToHost:self.serverData[@"host"] onPort:[self.serverData[@"port"] intValue] error:&error];
if (successs)
{    
 [self.clientSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
}
```

Comment: Minecraft PE uses a different protocol.  You want to look at http://wiki.vg/Pocket_Edition_Protocol_Documentation.  Trying to use the PC protocol wouldn't work.  (But for reference, you can find both the general packet format and the specifics of each packet on that page)

Comment: @Pokechu22, that's means I need to use UDP connection?

Comment: Among other things, yes; however, the login and all of the packets are also different (see http://wiki.vg/Pocket_Edition_Login and https://confluence.yawk.at/display/PEPROTOCOL).  PE is somewhat less well documented than the normal java edition, unfortunately.

Comment: The idea is that i need only connection request and ping, and for that I need to the format of sending data like here: https://github.com/brandon15811/Minecraft-PE-Proxy/blob/master/packettest.js